# Why does Douglas Crockford write `if` conditionals that are executed everytime except the first?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I've been reading his book and he does stuff like this is a lot. For example, on p. 48 of *JavaScript: The Good Parts*, he has the function

```
Cat.prototype.purr = function ( n )
    var i, s = '';
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i += 1 ) 
    {
        if (s) {
            s += '-';
        }
        s += 'r';
    }
    return s;
}
```

where the `if` conditional if essentially useless since it returns true every time but the first. The function could be written equivalently

```
Cat.prototype.purr = function ( n )
    var i, s = 'r';
    for ( i = 2; i < n; i += 1 ) 
    {
        s += '-r';
    }
    return s;
}
```

for better performance. Also, why does he define `i` outside the `for` loop?

Comment: Hopefully Crockford at least had a `{` to open the function ?

Comment: I prefer `Array(n).fill('r').join('-')`. More readable and probably faster.

Comment: I think `var i` is outside the loop as `for(var i...){...}` may infer block scope to those not familiar with the language.

Comment: In Crockfords defense he wrote the book almost ten years ago, when Ecma 5 wasn't even released

Comment: `the if conditional if essentially useless` - except that it essential to the correct functionality of that code

Answer (score 2):

The two functions are not the same. The original function returns an empty string of `n` is `0`. Your function returns `"r"` if `n` is `0`;

Comment: This is one reason people discourage micro-optimizations -- it's too tempting to write buggy code

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that this is just an example to illustrate a common need where you want to separate a list of items with a character like '-' or ','.

You might write a loop like this and instead of 'r' you would have the names of items.  E.g. "Bob-Mike-Jill-Jack"

To simplify the example for the book then he has just used 'r' which means the code could be written a different way like you say.  But for a generic list you do want to add the separator every time except the first.

In regards to the `var` placement if you are declaring `s` then it is less chars to declare `i` there as well rather than write out `var` again in the loop.  But I suspect it is probably just his idea of good practice to declare all variables that you use at the start of the function.